# When clicking on an item that has a submenu on a phone the submenu toggle action acts only on the arrow next to the text and not on the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

When clicking on an item that has a submenu on a phone the submenu toggle action acts only on the arrow next to the text and not on the text. I tried adding the class of the text in the on click function which makes the text slide up as with the arrow icon but it does not open the submenu like the arrow does.
Below is the javascript code for this.
Any ideas on how to customize the js code?

```html
function rep_menu(){
 $('.toggle-mobile-menu').on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.main-nav').toggleClass('active');
  if($(window).width()<768){
   $('.main-nav li.menu-item-has-children').append('<span class="btn-toggle-mobile-menu"></span>');
   $('.main-nav li.menu-item-has-children>.btn-toggle-mobile-menu').on('click',function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).prev().stop(true,false).slideToggle();
   });
  }
 });
}
```

I also found this part of code in my main js file.

```js
function init_MobileMenu(){

    $('body')
    .on('click','#hamburger-icon',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('body').toggleClass('opened-nav-animate');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('opened-nav');
      }, 100)

    });

    $('.open-submenu').on('click', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      $( this ).closest('li').toggleClass('active-menu-item');
      $( this ).closest('li').children( '.sub-menu-dropdown, .engo-megamenu-wrapper' ).slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
      var $navHeight = $(window).height() - $('.navbar-container').height();
      $('.main-nav-mobile').css({'max-height': $navHeight});
    });

  }
```

I add a link to my website here: [Link to Website](https://demo-nuts.myshopify.com/)

Comment: Maybe add the same event on the text?

Comment: Thats what i want to do but i do not know how to elicit the effect. If you can see in the code there is an append function that adds the arrow next to the text. But i was unable to find what effect it elicits to make the drop-down appear.

I tried adding the text class in here but it activates the slide effect without the dropdown opening :
$('.main-nav li.menu-item-has-children>.btn-toggle-mobile-menu').on('click',function(event)